# TSQL Convert Inline Function to Table Value Function for improved performance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I've inherited a database and ETL that needs some performance tuning.

Some of the long running stored procedures make calls to the following Inline function when querying large tables (millions of rows) and I think converting it into a Table value function will improve performance.

```
CREATE  FUNCTION dbo.ConvertAmountVerified 
(
    @amt VARCHAR(50)
)
RETURNS NUMERIC (18,3)  
AS
BEGIN   
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @Amount     NUMERIC(18, 3);
    DECLARE @TempAmount VARCHAR (50);
    DECLARE @Num        VARCHAR(1);
    DECLARE @LastChar   VARCHAR(1);
    DECLARE @Negative   BIT ;
    -- Get Last Character
    SELECT @LastChar = RIGHT(RTRIM(@amt), 1) ;

    SELECT @Num =
        CASE @LastChar  collate latin1_general_cs_as
            WHEN '{'  THEN '0'
            WHEN 'A' THEN '1'
            WHEN 'B' THEN '2'
            WHEN 'C' THEN '3'
            WHEN 'D' THEN '4'
            WHEN 'E' THEN '5'
            WHEN 'F' THEN '6'
            WHEN 'G' THEN '7'
            WHEN 'H' THEN '8'
            WHEN 'I' THEN '9'
            WHEN '}' THEN '0'
            WHEN 'J' THEN '1'
            WHEN 'K' THEN '2'
            WHEN 'L' THEN '3'
            WHEN 'M' THEN '4'
            WHEN 'N' THEN '5'
            WHEN 'O' THEN '6'
            WHEN 'P' THEN '7'
            WHEN 'Q' THEN '8'
            WHEN 'R' THEN '9'                   
            ---ASCII
            WHEN 'p' Then '0'
            WHEN 'q' Then '1'
            WHEN 'r' Then '2'
            WHEN 's' Then '3'
            WHEN 't' Then '4'
            WHEN 'u' Then '5'
            WHEN 'v' Then '6'
            WHEN 'w' Then '7'
            WHEN 'x' Then '8'
            WHEN 'y' Then '9'
        ELSE ''
        END; 

    SELECT @Negative =
        CASE @LastChar collate latin1_general_cs_as
            WHEN '{' THEN 0
            WHEN 'A' THEN 0
            WHEN 'B' THEN 0
            WHEN 'C' THEN 0
            WHEN 'D' THEN 0
            WHEN 'E' THEN 0
            WHEN 'F' THEN 0 
            WHEN 'G' THEN 0 
            WHEN 'H' THEN 0 
            WHEN 'I' THEN 0 
            WHEN '}' THEN 1                                         
            WHEN 'J' THEN 1 
            WHEN 'K' THEN 1 
            WHEN 'L' THEN 1 
            WHEN 'M' THEN 1 
            WHEN 'N' THEN 1 
            WHEN 'O' THEN 1 
            WHEN 'P' THEN 1 
            WHEN 'Q' THEN 1 
            WHEN 'R' THEN 1

            ---ASCII
            WHEN 'p' Then '1'
            WHEN 'q' Then '1'
            WHEN 'r' Then '1'
            WHEN 's' Then '1'
            WHEN 't' Then '1'
            WHEN 'u' Then '1'
            WHEN 'v' Then '1'
            WHEN 'w' Then '1'
            WHEN 'x' Then '1'
            WHEN 'y' Then '1'
        ELSE 0
        END; 
    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
    if (@Num ='')
    BEGIN
        SELECT @TempAmount=@amt;
    END; 
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT @TempAmount = SUBSTRING(RTRIM(@amt),1, LEN(@amt) - 1) + @Num;
    END;

    SELECT @Amount =CASE @Negative
                        WHEN 0 THEN (CAST(@TempAmount AS NUMERIC) / 100)
                        WHEN 1 THEN (CAST (@TempAmount AS NUMERIC) /100) * -1
                    END ;
    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @Amount;
END;
GO
```

Here's my conversion

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS dbo.ConvertAmountVerified_TVF
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ConvertAmountVerified_TVF
(
    @amt VARCHAR(50)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
RETURN
(
    WITH cteLastChar
    AS(
        SELECT LastChar = RIGHT(RTRIM(@amt), 1)
    )
    SELECT
        AmountVerified  = CAST(RET.Y AS NUMERIC(18,3))
    FROM (SELECT 1 t) t
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT Num =
            CAST(
                CASE 
                    WHEN CHARINDEX(L.LastChar  COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS, '{ABCDEFGHI}', 0) >0
                        THEN CHARINDEX(L.LastChar  COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS, '{ABCDEFGHI}', 0)-1
                    WHEN CHARINDEX(L.LastChar  COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS, 'JKLMNOPQR', 0) >0
                        THEN CHARINDEX(L.LastChar  COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS, 'JKLMNOPQR', 0)-1
                    WHEN CHARINDEX(L.LastChar  COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS, 'pqrstuvwxy', 0) >0
                        THEN CHARINDEX(L.LastChar  COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS, 'pqrstuvwxy', 0)-1
                ELSE NULL
                END
            AS VARCHAR(2))
        FROM
            cteLastChar L
    ) NUM
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT Negative =
            CASE 
                WHEN CHARINDEX(L.LastChar  COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS, '{ABCDEFGHI}', 0) >0
                    THEN 0
                WHEN CHARINDEX(L.LastChar  COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS, 'JKLMNOPQRpqrstuvwxy', 0) >0
                    THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END
        FROM cteLastChar L
    ) NEG
    OUTER APPLY(
        SELECT Amt= CASE
                        WHEN NUM.Num IS NULL
                            THEN @amt 
                        ELSE
                            SUBSTRING(RTRIM(@amt),1, LEN(@amt) - 1) + Num.Num
                    END
    ) TP
    OUTER APPLY(
        SELECT Y =  CASE
                        WHEN NEG.Negative = 0
                            THEN (CAST(TP.Amt AS NUMERIC) / 100)
                        WHEN NEG.Negative = 1
                            THEN (CAST (TP.Amt AS NUMERIC) /100) * -1
                    END
    ) RET
) ;

GO
```

Any suggestions for improvement would be appreciated.

Sample test data

```
SELECT dbo.ConvertAmountVerified('00064170')    --  641.700
SELECT * FROM dbo.ConvertAmountVerified_TVF('00064170') --  641.700

SELECT dbo.ConvertAmountVerified('00057600A')   --  5760.010
SELECT * FROM dbo.ConvertAmountVerified_TVF('00057600A')    --  5760.010

SELECT dbo.ConvertAmountVerified('00059224y')   --  -5922.490
SELECT * FROM dbo.ConvertAmountVerified_TVF('00059224y')    --  -5922.490
```